# логика работы .map and function

Tags: javascript

есть кусок кода:

```
[
  'Adam', 'has', 'a', 'dog', 'The', 'name', 'of', 'the', 'is', 'also'
].map(function (word) {
  this[word] = createWord(word);
}, this);

function createWord(word) { 
  return function (next) {
    if (arguments.length) { return word + ' ' + next;}
    return word + '.';
  };
}
```

если его вызвать

```
Adam(has(a(dog()))); // must return "Adam has a dog."
The(name(of(the(dog(is(also(Adam()))))))); // must return "The name of the dog is also Adam."
```

То он его и возвращает.

Как я понимаю кусок кода работает следующим образом:

1. массив прогоняется функцией `map()` и возвращает новый массив из функциями название которых также передается как аргумент в саму функцию.
2. в каждой функции есть возвращаемая функция которая каким то образом получает аргументом следующую функцию.

Вопрос:

1. как во внутреннюю функцию передается аргумент `next`?
2. почему функция начинает выполняться не из середины, а из края? (должна первая отрабатывать `dog()` а последняя `Adam()`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> массив прогоняется функцией map() и возвращает новый массив из функциями название которых также передается как аргумент в саму функцию.

Не совсем так. Название в функцию попадает снаружи, через механизм замыканий. Функции-"слова" - это инстансы одной и той же функции, определенной как

```
function (next) {
  if (arguments.length) { return word + ' ' + next;}
  return word + '.';
};
```

Как видно, у этой функции нет ни параметра word - ни даже имени. Параметр `word` относится к внешней функции, `createWord`.

Возможно, вас путает "магическая" инициализация списка функций через массив. Я вот тоже не сразу понял, что там происходит :) Для лучшего понимания верхний фрагмент можно написать вот так:

```
Adam = createWord("Adam");
has = createWord("has");
a = createWord("a");
// и так далее
```

Этот же фрагмент, в свою очередь, раскрывается в процессе выполнения во что-то наподобие вот такого кода:

```
Adam = function (next) {
  if (arguments.length) { return "Adam" + ' ' + next;}
  return "Adam" + '.';
};
has = function (next) {
  if (arguments.length) { return "has" + ' ' + next;}
  return "has" + '.';
};
a = function (next) {
  if (arguments.length) { return "a" + ' ' + next;}
  return "a" + '.';
};
```

> в каждой функции есть возвращаемая функция которая каким то образом получает аргументом следующую функцию.

Нет. Каждая функция получает в качестве аргумента *результат* выполнения другой функции. Это снимает заданные вами вопросы:

> 1) как во внутреннюю функцию передается аргумент next?

Напрямую. Поскольку "внутренняя" функция - это и есть та самая функция, которая так изящно притворяется словом - то и аргумент в нее попадает напрямую.

> 2) почему функция начинает выполняться не из середины, а из края? (должна первая отрабатывать dog() а последняя Adam())

Так и происходит. Первой отрабатывает `dog()` - а последней `Adam()`.

Comment: Понял!!! замыкание при создании - ето означает что в него сразу был передан аргумент еще при создании, и используется он только при выполнении внутренней функции. В внутренюю функцию приходит результат работы предыдущей функции и принимается как "next"(его наверно нада было назвать prev чтобы с толку не сбивало)  Спасибо что помогли разобратся